# How to show data labels when you mouse over data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting some data that looks like

```
931,Oxfordshire,9314125,123255,Larkmead School,Abingdon,125,124,20,SUPP,8
931,Oxfordshire,9314126,123256,John Mason School,Abingdon,164,164,25,6,16
931,Oxfordshire,9314127,123257,Fitzharrys School,Abingdon,150,149,9,0,11
931,Oxfordshire,9316076,123298,Our Lady's Abingdon,Abingdon,57,57,SUPP,SUPP,16
```

My basic steps are

```
df = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J', 'K'], header=None)
df.replace('SUPP', 3.0, inplace=True)
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df['KG'] = df['K']*1.0/df['G']
plt.plot(result['KG'])
plt.show()
```

However I would really like to get the name of each school when I mouse over the graph so I can explore the data.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3

Comment: Just to plug my own project a bit, have a look at `mpldatacursor`. In your case, you'd want to use the `hover=True` and `point_labels` options. Have a look at the example here: https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/blob/master/examples/labeled_points_example.py  I'll post a more detailed example based on your example if I get a chance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to plug my own project, have a look at `mpldatacursor`: https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor

As a basic example, just calling `datacursor(hover=True, point_labels=df['E'])` will get you 90% of the way to what you want. For example, taking your code snippet above:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

f = StringIO(
"""931,Oxfordshire,9314125,123255,Larkmead School,Abingdon,125,124,20,SUPP,8
931,Oxfordshire,9314126,123256,John Mason School,Abingdon,164,164,25,6,16
931,Oxfordshire,9314127,123257,Fitzharrys School,Abingdon,150,149,9,0,11
931,Oxfordshire,9316076,123298,Our Lady's Abingdon,Abingdon,57,57,SUPP,SUPP,16
""")
df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J', 'K'],
                 header=None)
df.replace('SUPP', 3.0, inplace=True)
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df['KG'] = df['K']*1.0/df['G']
plt.plot(df['KG'], marker='o')

datacursor(hover=True, point_labels=df['E'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

We'll get a popup label whenever the line is hovered over.

However, by design, the default behavior is to display the pop-up whenever the line is hovered over / clicked on.  Therefore, when using the `point_labels` option, the result may not quite be what you had in mind:

[image]

If you only want the pop-up to be displayed when the vertexes are hovered over, you can use a workaround similar to this: (There will be an option for only displaying the pop-up at vertexes in the next release, so this workaround won't be required in the future.)

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

f = StringIO(
"""931,Oxfordshire,9314125,123255,Larkmead School,Abingdon,125,124,20,SUPP,8
931,Oxfordshire,9314126,123256,John Mason School,Abingdon,164,164,25,6,16
931,Oxfordshire,9314127,123257,Fitzharrys School,Abingdon,150,149,9,0,11
931,Oxfordshire,9316076,123298,Our Lady's Abingdon,Abingdon,57,57,SUPP,SUPP,16
""")
df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J', 'K'],
                 header=None)
df.replace('SUPP', 3.0, inplace=True)
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df['KG'] = df['K']*1.0/df['G']
plt.plot(df['KG'], marker='o')

l, = plt.plot(df['KG'], marker='o', linestyle='', visible=False)
datacursor(l, hover=True, point_labels=df['E'])

plt.show()
```

Also, you might want to only display the school in question, instead of the x,y coordinates, etc. To change this, use a custom `formatter` function:

```
datacursor(l, hover=True, point_labels=df['E'],
           formatter=lambda **kwargs: kwargs['point_label'][0])
```

[image]

And finally, you might want a white box with a fancier arrow and a different relative position:

```
datacursor(l, hover=True, point_labels=df['E'], bbox=dict(fc='white'),
           formatter=lambda **kwargs: kwargs['point_label'][0], xytext=(0, 25),
           arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='simple', fc='white', alpha=0.5))
```

[image]

Just to put it all together into a runnable version for the last example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpldatacursor import datacursor

f = StringIO(
"""931,Oxfordshire,9314125,123255,Larkmead School,Abingdon,125,124,20,SUPP,8
931,Oxfordshire,9314126,123256,John Mason School,Abingdon,164,164,25,6,16
931,Oxfordshire,9314127,123257,Fitzharrys School,Abingdon,150,149,9,0,11
931,Oxfordshire,9316076,123298,Our Lady's Abingdon,Abingdon,57,57,SUPP,SUPP,16
""")
df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G', 'H','I','J', 'K'],
                 header=None)
df.replace('SUPP', 3.0, inplace=True)
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
df['KG'] = df['K']*1.0/df['G']
plt.plot(df['KG'], marker='o')

l, = plt.plot(df['KG'], marker='o', linestyle='', visible=False)
datacursor(l, hover=True, point_labels=df['E'], bbox=dict(fc='white'),
           formatter=lambda **kwargs: kwargs['point_label'][0], xytext=(0, 25))

plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a really great reply. I will study it in more depth later on today. Out of interest, is there any prospect of getting your project included in matplotlib one day?

Comment: Is there some way to save the resulting image?

Comment: I tried with my data where the only difference is that it is indexed by column 'D'. I get   File "./foo.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    formatter=lambda **kwargs: kwargs['point_label'][0], xytext=(0, 25))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I solved it by just using point_labels=list(result['E'])  . I am not sure why list is needed when the frame has an index.

Comment: @felix - In a nutshell, you have to specify `point_labels` if you want different labels for individual vertices. Matplotlib converts things to arrays when you plot the data. There's absolutely no way of telling that the original data was in a dataframe instead of say, a list or a numpy array.  (Keep in mind that matplotlib predates pandas by over a decade. The core data structures in matplotlib are numpy arrays.)  Therefore, you can't access the index of the dataframe. When `point_labels` isn't specified, kwarg passed into the `formatter` function is `None`, which causes the TypeError.

Comment: Thanks. I have added a new potentially much trickier question about mpldatacursor now. We need a mpldatacursor tag!

Comment: How can you make the point labels appear permanently?  This is just so I can print it.

Comment: @felix - Just don't use `hover=True`.  Then they'll only appear when you click on the point and won't go away until you press `d`. (That's the default behavior. I suggested `hover` because you mentioned wanting them to appear when you hovered over instead of clicked.)

Comment: @marshall - Sorry I didn't reply earlier. See my comment above this one. Basically, what you're wanting is the default behavior. Just don't use `hover=True` and the annotations will pop up when you click and stay there.

Comment: When I do that you only get one of the labels at a time. I would like them all to be showing or at least all the ones I have clicked on, whichever is easier to achieve. This is so that I can either print it or save the image and send it to someone.

Comment: @felix - Use `display='multiple'`.  You might also want `draggable=True` if you want to reposition the boxes.  Have a look at this example: https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor#draggable-boxes

Comment: Thank you! Your project really needs a) to be added to matplotlib and b) some way to save the interactive images :)

Comment: Oh and it would be even better if when you click again on a point it removes the label.

Comment: @felix - Good idea.  It's hard to implement that way at the moment (though it would be the most natural), but I should definitely add something to hide a specific annotation...

Comment: @JoeKington:  Did you ever implement to option to click to vertices?  Looking through the code but can't see it.  Also, if I wanted to do this on multiple lines, without just specifying "l" in the datacursor() call, how might I pass over the multiple point labels?