# cx-freeze exe from python27

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, cx-freeze

I am working with python27, Windows7 64bit, but my python version is 32bit to avoid some errors with different 64bit libraries.
I struggle with the cx-freeze. I tried some easy examples and it works. Even if I import some self-written scripts into my main.py script it still works after I freeze it. The problem is if I add the matplotlib to the file. I know that is a common problem, but I can't solve it in my case. My normal plot.py script works, see code below. Don't worry about the different arrays, I also tried it with simple arrays like x = [1,2,3,4] and y= [1,2,3,4]. The impoert matplotlib as mpl and the line below is just to erase the toolbar, I thought it is maybe a reason it doesn't work, but it isn't.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'

# change delimiter to |
csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')
# open file data.csv
csv_file_object = csv.reader(open("data.csv", 'r'), dialect='pipes')
# creates headers from the first line of the data file
header = csv_file_object.next()

data = []
for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
data = np.array(data)

y = []
for n1 in range(len(data)):
    y.append(float(data[n1][1]))
print y

time = []
for n2 in range(len(data)):
    time.append(int((data[n2][0].split('_')[1])[:4]))
print time


plt.plot(time, y)
plt.show()
```

I have tried the instruction from:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22024663/4072610)

but it didn't work. If I try this step by step the error raised if I try to execute the plot.exe is:

[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nefkln66k0spl9/error.png?dl=0)

Maybe it is just an easy mistake and someone can help me, but I also tried it with other setup files and so on. I can freeze an easy program with a GUI, so it shouldn,t be a problem with Tkinter.

Hope someone can help me!

Cheers
Max

edit: I found an example with a different backend which works see below link:
[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/juanpabloaj/7294839)
But I can't get my script running as an exe after I freezed it.

Comment: Try adding `'tkFileDialog'` to the includes list. Normally, cx_Freeze finds imported modules automatically, but when they're loaded through `six.moves`, it has trouble.

Comment: thx for the help but it doesn't help, still the same error :(

Comment: My mistake, try the same thing, but with `'FileDialog'`, the same name that's in the error message. I'm not sure why there are two things with very similar names.

Comment: yeah I already tried both packages, but didn't work either..

Comment: And are you sure it's *exactly* the same error as you showed? Can you show your setup.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found a solution to solve the problem.

My setup file looks like the following:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import matplotlib
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [
    cx_Freeze.Executable("newtry.py", base = base),
    ]

build_exe_options = {"includes":["FileDialog"],
                     "include_files":["test.csv"],
                     "excludes":[],
                     }
cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "script",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    version = "0.0",
    description = "A basic example",
    executables = executables)
```

Thanks for the hint from Thomas K. about the FileDialog, because without the includes "FileDialog" it doesn't work.

Furthermore to import the matplotlib in my executable file I have to use the following code:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

If I only use for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

it doesn't work. I don't know why but it doesn't? Anybody an answer?

With this header and this setup.py file I can use matplotlib in my main program as:

```
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

I hope if someone has the same problem like me he or she can use my example.

Cheers
Max