# Interactive matplotlib selection

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I would like to create a plot of say 5 poly-lines in matplotlib. Associated with each line is an ID. I would like to have to functionality that when I hover or click on the displayed line the corresponding ID is shown. I am planning to incorporate this plot in a wxPython App and pass the selected ID back to the wxPython app. Any pointers/examples to help me get started on this would be fantastic. 
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor , also chek this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998663/how-to-show-data-labels-when-you-mouse-over-data

Comment: Thanks. That is very helpful. I will follow the pointers.